# How to handle "grouping expanded data load complete" in a list view?

Tags: javascript, list-view

In SharePoint 2007 I run some code after a grouping is expanded by overriding the `ExpGroupRenderData` (the custom code contained Microsoft's original code with some added extra bits).

When this code runs, the data was loaded and therefore targeting the lis tview using the DOM and traversing over rows to set colors etc wasn't an issue!

We upgraded to 2010 and it appears this has now broken for the group being expanded. The `ExpGroupRenderData` function is not used to render the loaded data, it is only used to render the loading message.

**Question is**: is there an alternative in respect of firing some code when the data is loaded and the html has been updated with such.

**Note**: We CAN't modify the web part using SP Designer, and we are not using jQuery (yet).

Thanks

---

**Update**

---

For the time being I have a solution albeit a not ideal one! I'v removed the expand-on-load behaviour. and have introduced a delay in the ExpGroupRenderData before colouring the cells (enough for the data to load and appear). As I say not ideal but following an upgrade need a tick in the box so I can move onto the next thing :)